# Como realizar dos consultas SELECT en SQLITE?

Tags: sqlite, sqlite3

deceo evalular que ambos campos de ambas tablas tengan el mismo dato STR. para que me cuente cuantos nombres existes en la tabla clientes compra.

```
SELECT count(nombre_cliente) FROM clientes_compra WHERE nombre_cliente = 'jorgito' AND  SELECT nombre FROM clientes = 'jorgito'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitas hacer un `JOIN` entre ambas tablas, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT 
    count(cc.nombre_cliente) 
FROM clientes_compra AS cc
INNER JOIN clientes AS c ON cc.nombre_cliente = c.nombre 
WHERE cc.nombre_cliente = 'jorgito';
```

Comment: Gracias compañero, funciono bastante bien.